# Getting exception when attempting to fill a DataSet object with OdbcDataAdapter results?

Tags: c#, sql, exception, odbc

I am attempting to take the result of ODBC call (a table) and put it into a DataSet object.

I have tried adding and removing "Table" from the .Fill() method

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=***;HOST=***;SOCKET=***"); 
OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand();
comm.Connection = conn; 

comm.CommandText = "select * from tableX";
conn.Open();

OdbcDataAdapter adaptor = new OdbcDataAdapter(comm); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

adaptor.Fill(ds, "Table");  //here is where the exception comes up.
```

Here is the exception I get:

The error message TableOrViewNotFound could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that \en-US\SQLEngineMessages.xml exists.

Comment: In the database there is no table "tableX".

Comment: Qeury : "select * from tableX";  Does adaptor contain any data?

Comment: You are right, that query was just not viable in that specific server/database! Thank you @jdweng